# RESTful API endpoint using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

At school I got a task in which I have to do the following task in the Java programming language:

> Implement the RESTful endpoint API, which simultaneously makes calls
> to the following websites:
>
> - https://pizzerijalimbo.si/meni/
> - https://pizzerijalimbo.si/kontakt/
> - https://pizzerijalimbo.si/my-account/
> - https://pizzerijalimbo.si/o-nas/
>
> The input for the endpoint is ‘integer’, which represents the number
> of simultaneous calls to the above web pages (min 1 represents all
> consecutive calls, max 4 represents all simultaneous calls).
>
> Extracts a short title text from each page and saves this text in a
> common global structure (array, folder (). The program should also
> count successful calls. Finally, the service should list the number of
> successful calls, the number of failed calls and the saved address
> texts from all web pages.

I followed some YouTube tutorials and only managed to display data from a random API URL to my local host site.

`TestApplication.java` (Main file)

```
   package com.example.test;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class TestApplication {
    
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(){
            return new RestTemplate();
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

`APIcontroller.java` (Second file)

```
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class APIcontroller {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private static String url = "https://www.result.si/projekti/";

    @GetMapping("/countries")
    public List<Object> getCountries() {
        Object[] countries = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Object[].class);
        return Arrays.asList(countries);
    }

}
```

Please help me with some basic guidance or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood this correctly you need to have an endpoint with a query parameter as follows:

```java
@RestController
public class APIcontroller {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    List<String> websites = Arrays.asList("https://pizzerijalimbo.si/meni/", 
        "https://pizzerijalimbo.si/kontakt/", 
        "https://pizzerijalimbo.si/my-account/", 
        "https://pizzerijalimbo.si/o-nas/");

    @GetMapping("/data-scraping")
    public List<Object> getData(@RequestParam(required = true) int numberOfWebsites) {
        List<String> websitesToScrape = websites.subList(0, numberOfWebsites);
    
        for (String website : websitesToScrape) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(website).get();
            // here you need to extract a the title text from each page and store it in a common global variable
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Maybe it is even better to get the websites' content using Jsoup, so that it is easier to get the data that you need from it. More details at:

- https://jsoup.org/
- https://www.baeldung.com/java-with-jsoup

Answer (score 0):

Get the input integer as a Query Parameter and wite a switch case. If it is 4, then using Executor framework, create teh required threads and parallel make the rest template call for the 4 unique URLS. Then grap the html content and the http status. Store it in a HashMap and print the results.

Comment: Use the RestTemplate#exchange methods that return a ResponseEntity. This gives you access to the status line and headers (and the body obviously).